# Javascript library to generate iCal format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, icalendar, rfc5545

Does anyone know if there is any JavaScript libraries that generates iCal format? (RFC 5545 or RFC 2445 standard)

It would be good if it also provides user interface for it. Something similar to OWA Repetition window or Google Calendar repeat popup.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: did the checked answer worked for you? I can't seem to get the examples to work with ical...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but this looks like it will work [jQuery iCalendar](http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html).